# Team Exlorer 2013 - how to change check in policy?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, checkin-policy

We've migrated projects and code from TFS2008 to TFS2013. Can some kind person tell me how to change or edit the Check In Policy that we were using in TFS2008? Our old policy is proving a bit troublesome in the 2013 world, and I can't find this anywhere in the online documentation for Team Explorer 2013

Answer (score 1):

Found it! Not in Team Explorer after all, found in Team>Team Project Settings>Source Control instead. Same as VS2008 :-( it seems one of the policies I was using is no longer available.

Comment: Which check-in policy is missing? Some policies are installed with TFS Power Tool, like Custom Path Policy, Forbidden Patterns Policy and Work Item Query Policy. You need to install TFS2013 Power Tool if you would like to use them, go: https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/f017b10c-02b4-4d6d-9845-58a06545627f